# How to rollback transactions of entire loop in spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions

So I have a loop with multiple transactions happening within it and if one item is invalid I want the program to rollback all previous transactions. 
I'm using spring boot for all my dependency injection and jpa functionality

This snippet is a service method in services

```
@Override
@Transactional(rollbackOn = ItemInvalidException.class)
public void saveAll (List<Item> items) throws ItemInvalidException{
    for(Item item :Items){
        if(item==invalid)
            throw new ItemInvalidException();
        itemRepository.save(item)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, but do you have a question ? Is it working, not working ? Don't hesitate to refer to this in order to ask relevant questions where people can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Basically, for you, we don't know if you are having a problem, if you tried things to make your code work. Are you facing a wrong behaviour ?

Comment: *"How to rollback transactions of entire loop in spring?"* Seems you already did it with that `@Transactional` annotation, so why are you asking?

Comment: You will get better answers if you explain what specific problem you encounter, i.e. expected vs. observed outcome of your snippet of code. Giving a minimal, reproducible example is probably the best way to go. Help people help you :-)

Answer (score 2):

The ideal behavior of Transaction is exactly what was mentioned by you.Transactions will be committed only at the end of method and its not on each record.At any point in the iteration,if we get an exception, the entire transaction will be rolled back without saving any data.

If you feel this behavior is not happening, then i guess you are invoking the `@Transactional`method with in the same bean.`@Transactional` only works on methods invoked on proxies created by spring. It means, that when you create a `@Service` or other bean, method called from the outside will be transactional. If invoked from within bean, nothing will happen, as it doesn't pass through proxy object.

Am not sure what exactly is your issue, if you feel that transaction is never happening then above thing might be a reason.Hope this might help you